# Default going to homepage in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

Hello to all the friends, I am a Django developer and I want to go to a specific url with slug, but when I try that, automatically the server goes to homepage, I don't know that what should I do.

views.py

```
def ChangeQuizInfol(request,slugp):
print("changequizinfo is running.")
if request.method == 'POST':
    
        
    print("is post.")

    form = NewAzmoonForms()
    # else:
    #     form = NewAzmoonForms(request.POST, instance=quiz)
    #     if form.is_valid():
    #         form.save()
else:
    quiz = QuizStudent.objects.get(slug=slugp)
    print(quiz)
    questions = Questions.objects.filter(quiz_id=quiz.id)
    print(questions)
try:
    try:
        co = {
            "quiz":quiz,
            "form":form,
            "questions":questions
        }
    except:
        co = {
            "form":form,
        }
except:
    co = {
    }
return render(request, "komaki/per.html", co)
def ListsTeacherQuizes(request):
    print("list is running.")
    user = request.user
    quizes = QuizStudent.objects.filter(author_id = user.id)
    return render(request, "komaki/lists.html",{"quizes":quizes})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = 'komaki'
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.avaL,name='avaL'),
    path('create/',views.create_question,name='create_question'),
    path('start/',views.startazmoon,name='startazmoon'),
    path('azm/',views.azmoonpage,name='azmoonpage'),
    path('Sokht/',views.NeveshtanAzmoon,name='NeveshtanAzmoon'),
    path("NeveshtanQuestion/",views.NeveshtanQuestion,name='NeveshtanQuestion'),
    path('ShowQuizStudents/',views.ShowQuizes,name='ShowQuizes'),
    path('<slug>',views.EachQuiz,name='EachQuiz'),
    path("equation/", views.Equation, name='Equation'),
    path("geo/",views.Geo, name='Geo'),
    path("Chang/", views.Chang, name='Chang'),
    path("AskAndAnswer/",views.AskAndAnswer, name="AskAndAnswer"),
    path("Pish/",views.Pishrafteh, name="Pishrafteh"),
    path("UploadVideo/",views.Videoupload,name="Videoupload"),
    path("Lists/",views.ListsTeacherQuizes, name="ListsTeacherQuizes"),
    path("<slugp>", views.ChangeQuizInfol, name="ChangeQuizInfol"),
]
```

lists.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block head %}
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
  {% for quiz in quizes %}
    <div class="quiz{{ quiz.id }}" style="margin-top: 100px;">
        <a href="{% url "komaki:ChangeQuizInfol" slugp=quiz.correct_slug %}">{{quiz.name}}</a>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

per.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block head %}{% endblock head %}
{% block body %}

<h2>{{quiz.name}}</h2>


{% endblock body %}
```

It doesn't go to that specific url, instead goes to homepage.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Shouldn't `path("<slugp>` be ``path("<slugp:slug>.?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i use slug urls correctly in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59535275/how-do-i-use-slug-urls-correctly-in-django)